# Return a new int array of length n, containing the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... n-1

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

While I was practicing Java problems on coding bat I came across the following problem statement.

Problem:-

> Given a number n, create and return a new int array of length n,
> containing the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... n-1. The given n maybe 0, in which
> case just return a length 0 array. You do not need a separate
> if-statement for the length-0 case; the for-loop should naturally
> execute 0 times in that case, so it just works.

Example:-

```
fizzArray(4) → [0, 1, 2, 3]
fizzArray(1) → [0]
fizzArray(10) → [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

My solution:-

```
public int[] fizzArray(int n) {
  int[] myArray=new int[n];
  for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
    myArray[i]=i;
}
    return myArray;
}
```

My Problem:-

Though my code works, I was wondering if I can solve this question without using a loop. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You could use a while loop, recursion, int stream...

Comment: Note that `i<n` is more idiomatic than `i<=n-1`.

Comment: What difference will it make(b/w i<n and i<=n-1). Curious to know!

Answer (score 4):

Using an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) may be more elegant:

```
public int[] fizzArray(int n) {
    return IntStream.range(0, n).toArray();
}
```